# Protractor and Angular's $q.defer

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-promise, deferred

I have angular code like this:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
    console.log(1);
    clearCookies().then(function() {
        console.log(2);
        $state.go('loginScreen');
   });
};

function clearCookies() {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    if(something) {
       sendSomeRequest().then(function() {
           defer.resolve();
       });
    } else {
        defer.resolve();
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```

$scope.logout function is calling on element's ng-click.
And I have test:

```
element(by.css('[class="logout-button"]')).click();
```

I'll never see "2" in console, through I think "then" callback is never triggered when it's triggered by protractor. And it's just never make "$state.go" action.
Maybe I missed something? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You should return defer.promise;

You can find more information about $q [here in the official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: In real code it returns defer.promise. Sorry my bad. Fixed in question.

Comment: Your request is not failing?

Comment: No, it's ok. The problem is present event if we falling to "else" statement and don't have a request.